# Double#parseDouble not throwing a NullPointerException when attemping to parse empty substrings/tokens

Tags: java, input, java.util.scanner

I was working on some code using try-catch and I needed empty substrings to throw an exception when doing `Double.parseDouble()` (in this case, I presume it would be a `NullPointerException`).

My question is why this code doesn't throw an exception if I enter something like `, , ,` (space-comma-space-comma-space-comma) or similar (which should split the string into three whitespaces, if I understand correctly):

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] inputParts = null;
String inputLine = input.nextLine();

// the matches() here prevents this from happening, but I still don't understand
// why an exception isn't thrown
if ((inputLine.contains(",") || inputLine.contains(" ")) && !inputLine.matches("\\s+")) { 
    inputParts = inputLine.split("\\s*(,*\\s+)|(,+)");
}

for (int i = 0; i < inputParts.length; ++i) {
    // this prints nothing -- not even a new line. Same behavior even if I don't parseDouble
    // and just print the string directly
    System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(inputParts[i])); 
}
```

If I try to `parseDouble` from an empty string `""` or `" "` without taking user input like this it does throw an exception.

I'm quite confused as to why this is happening, considering the code I was working on does work except when I enter something like the above (although I fixed it by checking to see if each substring was only whitespace and throwing the appropriate exception manually).

Thanks.

Comment: maybe it is not getting into the split

Comment: What jdk version you're using?

Comment: @kucing_terbang I've tried this on multiple computers using jdk 8 update 77.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `inputLine.split("\\s*(,*\\s+)|(,+)")`? Do you want to split the string by using a comma as separator?